# How to add like on instagram media using php

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

i'm building a small App for instagram and i need to post a like on any media

```
$uurl='https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/'.$media_id.'/likes';
            $inst_stream2 = callInstagram($uurl);
            $results2 = json_decode($inst_stream2, true);

    function callInstagram($url)
       {
    $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
      ));

     $result = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
     return $result;
    }
```

but it doesn't post any like !!

Comment: This is PHP, right? Do you check for errors? You can't just blindly call things and hope they work.

Comment: there's no errors , it just return an empty object!!

Comment: Do you have an authenticated user that has granted your application rights to post likes? You will need that before you can just create a like.

Comment: yes , i'have my script fetch all media of current authenticated user and number of likes...etc. but when i'm attempt to add like on any media it doesn't response for that ... but when i used the https://apigee.com/console/instagram console and make a request to add like to a media it work well !!

Comment: @BillRollins here's my problem!